# Breadcrumbs on Product Page Always Show Wrong Product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

If I visit a product page, for example: http://woocommerce-176860-513159.cloudwaysapps.com/product/ardbeg-grooves-limited-edition/

And look at the breadcrumbs, they show the wrong product. It turns out the product that the breadcrumbs show is the last updated product in my backend…

How do I get my breadcrumbs working again and showing the current product that I am visiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a custom plugin I made was globally looping through some proucts with a WP_Query. This meant that the breadcrumbs were being set to the last product in that loop, not the product on that page... the solution was to reset the query in my plugin using `wp_reset_query();`. Always reset your queries!